# Finding a MGF from a specific PMF, trouble with reducing a summation.

Tags: probability, statistics, summation

First of all, yes this is homework. I will give you the question and what I have tried. I am looking for a push in the right direction.

**The context**

\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{3})^{x-1} & x=1,2,...\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The question is to find the MGF for $t < \ln(3)$

**What I have tried**
\begin{align*}
&\text{because } 1=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x-1}\\
&\text{then } M_{X}(t) = E(e^{tX}) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}\frac{2}{3}(\dfrac{1}{3})^{x-1}\\
&\text{for when } t < \ln(3)\\
&\text{makes } \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-1}(e^{tx})\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{x}\\ 
&= 2\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{t}}{3}\right)^{x}\\
&= 2\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)^{x} \text{ for } a  < 3\\
\end{align*}

**The Problem**

I am fairly certain a MGF should be a function, that is not in summation form. But I am not sure how to reduce it any further.

Also I know I have 1 rep on this site but I have a decent amount of rep on SO so I will reward an answer not just take it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:  Recall that for any $|z| < 1$, we have $$\sum_{x=0}^\infty z^x = \frac{1}{1-z},$$ which is the formula for an infinite geometric series with common ratio $z$.  It follows from your penultimate step that $$M_X(t) = 2 \sum_{x=0}^\infty (e^t/3)^x = \frac{2}{1 - (e^t/3)}, \quad |e^t/3| < 1,$$ and this also is the source of the condition that $e^t < 3$, or $t < \log 3$.

Comment: Thanks! I actually knew about that geometric series formula but I couldn't connect the dots. Thanks for your help.